# How to configure Sharepoint site for intranet?

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, intranet

I have Designed a small site in sharepoint on my virtual PC environment.

I want to access it from out side of virtual PC environment such as other local LAN machines [like intranet].

How do i configure (IIS/Sharepoint Adm) to make my site as an intranet site? I googled it, but not able to get desired information. I don't have much knowledge in IIS setting also, kindly provide any help in layman style.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure VM to share your network adapter. You did not provide your HW details so it is hard to give precise details, but [click here](http://www.andornot.com/about/developerblog/2008/09/virtual-pc-2007-networking-tip.aspx) for some ideas.

Your sites should be available as e.g. http://your-vm-name-Port. If you want other users to access a SharePoint site with friendly address e.g. http://home.companyabc.com you will need to define a DNS entry for **home.companyabc.com** and point this entry to your VM. You will also need to [configure Alternate Access Mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx) for SharePoint site collection you want to expose.

---

If this is production environment you should not run it on top of Virtual PC as it is designed just for personal VM testing and stuff. You can move your VHDs to [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv.aspx) or [Virtual Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this [MOSS 2007 – Step by Step](http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/MOSS-2007-e28093-Step-by-Step-e28093-Table-of-Contents.aspx)

Hope this helps,
Vivek